# sshfs is not mounting the directory using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I wrote sshfs ansible playbook to mount remote directory from server.
  When i am executing the same command manually on shell it is working(remote directory contents are seen). But when i am trying with ansible playbook, the remote directory is not mounting as expected.

```
user_allow_other  -> Added this line /etc/fuse.conf

Added the below lines: /etc/ssh/ssh_config
SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

With out these addition also, running manually it is working.
But ansible playbook it is not mounting the remote directory, but showing as playbook successful.

```
**fuse.yml**

---
- hosts: server
  become: yes
  tasks:

    - name: Mount Media Directory
      shell: echo root123 | sshfs -o password_stdin,reconnect,nonempty,allow_other,idmap=user stack@10.1.1.1:/home/stack /mnt/server1


root@stack-VirtualBox:~/playbook# ansible-playbook fusessh.yml -vvv

<10.1.1.1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: stack
<10.1.1.1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/stack/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o User=stack -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/88bbb1646b 10.1.1.1 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /tmp/stack/ansible/ansible-tmp-1568065019.557693-124891815649027/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.1.1.1> (0, b'', b'')
changed: [10.1.1.1] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "echo root123 | sshfs -o password_stdin,reconnect,nonempty,allow_other,idmap=user stack@10.1.1.1:/home/stack /mnt/server1",
    "delta": "0:00:00.548757",
    "end": "2019-09-09 15:37:00.579023",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "echo root123 | sshfs -o password_stdin,reconnect,nonempty,allow_other,idmap=user stack@10.1.1.1:/home/stack /mnt/server1",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2019-09-09 15:37:00.030266",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************
10.1.1.1                   : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Are you using ansible < 2.6.4 ? There seems to be [a related bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/45899).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sshfs action is performed on remote instead of locally. The reason why it is working  manually because the sshs login action is performed on the local shell not on remote server. I modified your playbook by adding **local_action**. I have tested the same and it is working fine.

```
---
- hosts: server
  become: yes
  tasks:

    - name: Mount Media Directory
      local_action: shell echo root123 | sshfs -o password_stdin,reconnect,nonempty,allow_other,idmap=user stack@10.1.1.1:/home/stack /mnt/server1
```